# Problema tr escondida nao mostra no sitio certo depois de retornado json

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma tabela que me lista todos os utilizadores, uma `tr` escondida em que quando clico no botão mostrar jogadores abre mostra essa `tr` com uma tabela dentro lista abaixo do utilizador que eu estou a querer mostrar os jogadores dele.
O que me esta acontecer e que por exemplo listo 6 utilizadores clico no botão mostrar jogadores do primeiro utilizador, mostra a `tr` escondida em ultimo lugar da tabela invés de mostrar logo abaixo primeiro utilizador

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on("click", "#show_jogadores", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id_agente = $(this).data("id-agente");
    $('#content-'+id_agente+'').toggle();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="table-check">
        Função
    </th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Moeda</th>
    <th>Jogadores</th>
    <th>Credit Line</th>
    <th>Total disponível</th>
    <th>Balance</th>
    <th>Total Players Balance</th>
    <th>Crédito disponível</th>
    <th>Ações</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="resultado_agent_tree"> 
@foreach($lista_tree as $agent_tree)
<tr>
    <td align="left">
        <div id="show-list" data-tt-id="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" class="fa fa-plus" data-tt-parent="" style="float: left; font-size: 18px; margin: 3px 5px 0px 0px; cursor: pointer;">
        </div>
        <div id="show-list-content" data-tt-id="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" class="fa fa-plus" data-tt-parent="" style="float: left; font-size: 18px; display: none; margin: 3px 5px 0px 0px; cursor: pointer;">
        </div>
        <div id="hidden-list" data-tt-id="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" class="fa fa-minus" data-tt-parent="" style="float: left; font-size: 18px; display: none; margin: 3px 5px 0px 0px; cursor: pointer;">
        </div>
        <div style="width: 37px; height: 25px; line-height: 23px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;  border-radius: 12.5px; box-sizing: border-box; text-transform: uppercase; border: 1px solid #26a677; color: #26a677; float: left;">{{ $agent_tree->sign }}
        </div> 
    </td>
    <td class="table-check">
        {{ $agent_tree->username_agente }}  
    </td>
    <td class="table-check">
        {{ $agent_tree->code }}
    </td>
    <td class="table-check" align="center">
        {{ $agent_tree->count_players }}
    </td>
    <td class="table-check" align="right">
        {{ number_format($agent_tree->credit_line,2,",","") }} €
    </td>
    <td class="table-date">
        {{ number_format($agent_tree->balance_agentes,2,",","") }} €
    </td>
    <td class="table-check" align="right">
        @if($agent_tree->balance_real < 0)
            <div style="color: #ff7b84"> {{ number_format($agent_tree->balance_real,2,",","") }} €</div>
        @else   
            <div> {{ number_format($agent_tree->balance_real,2,",","") }} €</div>
        @endif  
    </td>
    <td class="table-check" align="right">
        {{ number_format($agent_tree->balance_player,2,",","") }} €     
    </td>
    <td class="table-check" align="right">
        @if($agent_tree->balance_real < 0)
            {{ number_format($agent_tree->balance_agentes -+ $agent_tree->balance_real,2,",","") }} €
        @else       
            {{ number_format($agent_tree->balance_agentes - $agent_tree->balance_real,2,",","") }} €
        @endif  
    </td>
    <td class="table-check">
        <div id="show_jogadores" data-id-agente="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" style="width: 100px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid #c2c5cd; text-align: center; line-height: 28px; float: left; border-right: none; cursor: pointer;">
            <p>JOGADORES</p>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 30px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid #c2c5cd; text-align: center; line-height: 28px; float: left; cursor: pointer;">
            <i id="botao_ver_opcoes" data-id-agente="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="opcoes-{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" style="width: 130px; margin-top: 30px; background-color: white; border: 1px solid #c2c5cd; z-index: 10; position: absolute; display: none; border-top: none;">
            <!--<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-add-credito" id="add-credito-btn" data-id-agente="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" data-id-line="{{ $agent_tree->credit_line }}" style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">TRANSFERIR</div>-->
            <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-info-agente" id="info-user-btn" data-id-agente="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">INFORMAÇÕES</div>
            <!--<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-update-senha" id="change-pwd-btn" data-id-agente="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">SENHA</div>
            <div style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">MENSAGEM</div>-->
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach 
<tr id="content-{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" style="display: none;" bgcolor="#d6d6df">
    <td colspan="10" style="padding:0; margin:0; ">
        <div class="table-responsive alt-table">
            <table style=" margin: 10px auto; width: 50%;" class="table table-bordered">
                 <thead>
                    <tr bgcolor="#e0e0e2">
                        <th class="table-check">
                            ID do Jogador
                        </th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Primeiro Nome</th>
                        <th>Sobrenome</th>
                        <th>Balance</th>
                        <th>Ações</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                     @foreach($players as $players_dados)
                    <tr>
                        <td class="table-check">
                            {{ $players_dados->id }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="table-check">
                            {{ $players_dados->username }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="table-check">
                            {{ $players_dados->f_name }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="table-check">
                            {{ $players_dados->l_name }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="table-check">
                            {{ number_format($players_dados->balance,2,",","") }} €
                        </td>
                        <td class="table-check">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-add-credito-jogador" id="add-credito-btn-jogador" data-id-jogador="{{ $players_dados->id }}" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-update-senha" id="change-pwd-btn" data-id-jogador="{{ $players_dados->id }}" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach 
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Como podem ver na foto a seta amarela aquele conteudo deveria de mostrar abaixo do utilizador carlos e mostrou em baixo.

**JSON**

```
  $return['conteudo'] .= '
            <tr data-tr-pai="'.$resultado->parent.'">
                <td>
                    '.$botao_mais.'
                    <table width="100" style="margin-left:20px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                <div style="width: 37px; height: 25px; line-height: 23px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;  border-radius: 12.5px; box-sizing: border-box; text-transform: uppercase; border: 1px solid #26a677; color: #26a677; float:left;">'.$resultado->sign.'</div> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td class="table-check">
                    '.$resultado->username_agente.'  
                </td>
                <td class="table-check">
                    '.$resultado->code.'  
                </td>
                <td class="table-check" align="center">
                    '.$resultado->count_players.'
                </td>
                <td class="table-check" align="right">
                    '.number_format($resultado->credit_line,2,",","").' €
                </td>
                <td class="table-date">
                    '.number_format($resultado->balance_agentes,2,",","").' €
                </td>
                <td class="table-check" align="right">
                    '.$balance.'
                </td>
                <td class="table-check" align="right">
                    '.number_format($resultado->balance_player,2,",","").' €    
                </td>
                <td class="table-check" align="right">
                   '.$credito_disponivel.' 
                </td>
                <td class="table-check">
                    <div id="show_jogadores" data-id-agente="'.$resultado->user_id.'" style="width: 100px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid #c2c5cd; text-align: center; line-height: 28px; float: left; border-right: none; cursor: pointer;">
                        <p>JOGADORES</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 30px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid #c2c5cd; text-align: center; line-height: 28px; float: left; cursor: pointer;">
                        <i id="botao_ver_opcoes" data-id-agente="'.$resultado->user_id.'" class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div id="opcoes-'.$resultado->user_id.'" style="width: 130px; margin-top: 30px; border: 1px solid #c2c5cd; background-color: white; position: absolute; z-index: 10; display: none; border-top: none;">
                        <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-add-credito" id="add-credito-btn" data-id-agente="'.$resultado->user_id.'" data-my-balance="'.Auth::user()->balance_real.'" data-my-available-credit="'.Auth::user()->credit_line.'" data-id-line="'.$resultado->balance_real.'" data-id-credit-line="'.$resultado->credit_line.'" style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">TRANSFERIR</div>
                        <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-info-agente" id="info-user-btn" data-id-agente="'.$resultado->user_id.'" style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">INFORMAÇÕES</div>
                        <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-update-senha" id="change-pwd-btn" data-id-agente="'.$resultado->user_id.'" style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">SENHA</div>
                        <div style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">MENSAGEM</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="content-'.$resultado->user_id.'" style=" display:none; bgcolor="#d6d6df">
                <td colspan="10" style="padding:0; margin:0; ">
                    <div class="table-responsive alt-table">
                        <table style=" margin: 10px auto; width: 50%;" class="table table-bordered">
                             <thead>
                                <tr bgcolor="#e0e0e2">
                                    <th class="table-check">
                                        ID do Jogador
                                    </th>
                                    <th>Username</th>
                                    <th>Primeiro Nome</th>
                                    <th>Sobrenome</th>
                                    <th>Balance</th>
                                    <th>Ações</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                '.$conteudo_players.'
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>    
                </td>    
            </tr>
        ';

    }
    return response()->json($return);
}
```

Comment: Não consigo ver a imagem, então me diga: ele mostra a <tr> certa, só que por ultimo na tabela? Ou mostra a ultima <tr> da tabela?

Comment: ele mostra a tr certa so nunca no lugar certo tem que aparecer sempre abaixo do utilizador

Comment: Se tu tirar o display none da <tr> ela tá carregando no lugar certo?

Comment: tambem nao os utilizadores vao listando quando clico num botao mais retorna um json que tras os utilizadores filhos e essa tr escondida mas tirei o display:none e nao esta a mostrar no sitio certo

Comment: Então o problema não é nesse código js e nem no show/hide do elemento. Talvez tu deva mudar a pergunta ou ir fazendo testes isolados pra descobrir o problema. =T

Comment: Coloquei o php que e retornado tem a tal tr abaixo o problema deve ser ai veja agora se me consegue ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Não estou seguro de qual pré-processador estás a utilizar para poderes usar             esses elementos `@if`/`@foreach`/etc, mas está claro que o problema está na ordem que constróis estas tabelas:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <!-- etc. -->
    <tbody id="resultado_agent_tree"> 
        @foreach($lista_tree as $agent_tree)
            <tr>
                <!-- Cria a linha de cada utilizador -->
                <div id="show_jogadores" data-id-agente="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}"
                     style="/* estilos CSS */">
                <p>JOGADORES</p>
              </div>
            <tr>
        @endforeach
        <tr id="content-{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" style="display: none;"
            bgcolor="#d6d6df">
            <td colspan="10" style="padding:0; margin:0; ">
                <div class="table-responsive alt-table">
                    <table style=" margin: 10px auto; width: 50%;"
                           class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <!-- etc. -->
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($players as $players_dados)
                                <tr>
                                    <!-- somente aqui vão as informações dos jogadores -->
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Como vês, crias uma tabela, e depois de abrires o `<tbody>` iteras sobre os utilizadores, criando uma linha `<tr>` para cada um. **Depois de iterares por todos eles,** crias uma última linha `<tr>`, oculta, e dentro dela crias outra tabela em cujo corpo iteras sobre `$players` para listares os jogadores de um único utilizador (provavelmente o último).

O que queres, na realidade, é terminar aquele `@endforeach` imediatamente antes da *tag* de fechamento `</tbody>` em vez de fazê-lo imediatamente após a *tag* `</tr>`, como estás fazendo. Assim ele gerará um par de `<tr>`s, uma para cada utilizador, alternadamente do utilizador e dos jogadores respetivos.

O código corrigido ficaria assim:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-check">
                Função
            </th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Moeda</th>
            <th>Jogadores</th>
            <th>Credit Line</th>
            <th>Total disponível</th>
            <th>Balance</th>
            <th>Total Players Balance</th>
            <th>Crédito disponível</th>
            <th>Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="resultado_agent_tree"> 
        @foreach($lista_tree as $agent_tree)
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <div id="show-list" data-tt-id="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" class="fa fa-plus" data-tt-parent="" style="float: left; font-size: 18px; margin: 3px 5px 0px 0px; cursor: pointer;">
                    </div>
                    <div id="show-list-content" data-tt-id="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" class="fa fa-plus" data-tt-parent="" style="float: left; font-size: 18px; display: none; margin: 3px 5px 0px 0px; cursor: pointer;">
                    </div>
                    <div id="hidden-list" data-tt-id="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" class="fa fa-minus" data-tt-parent="" style="float: left; font-size: 18px; display: none; margin: 3px 5px 0px 0px; cursor: pointer;">
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 37px; height: 25px; line-height: 23px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;  border-radius: 12.5px; box-sizing: border-box; text-transform: uppercase; border: 1px solid #26a677; color: #26a677; float: left;">{{ $agent_tree->sign }}
                    </div> 
                </td>
                <td class="table-check">
                    {{ $agent_tree->username_agente }}  
                </td>
                <td class="table-check">
                    {{ $agent_tree->code }}
                </td>
                <td class="table-check" align="center">
                    {{ $agent_tree->count_players }}
                </td>
                <td class="table-check" align="right">
                    {{ number_format($agent_tree->credit_line,2,",","") }} €
                </td>
                <td class="table-date">
                    {{ number_format($agent_tree->balance_agentes,2,",","") }} €
                </td>
                <td class="table-check" align="right">
                    @if($agent_tree->balance_real < 0)
                        <div style="color: #ff7b84"> {{ number_format($agent_tree->balance_real,2,",","") }} €</div>
                    @else   
                        <div> {{ number_format($agent_tree->balance_real,2,",","") }} €</div>
                    @endif  
                </td>
                <td class="table-check" align="right">
                    {{ number_format($agent_tree->balance_player,2,",","") }} €     
                </td>
                <td class="table-check" align="right">
                    @if($agent_tree->balance_real < 0)
                        {{ number_format($agent_tree->balance_agentes -+ $agent_tree->balance_real,2,",","") }} €
                    @else       
                        {{ number_format($agent_tree->balance_agentes - $agent_tree->balance_real,2,",","") }} €
                    @endif  
                </td>
                <td class="table-check">
                    <div id="show_jogadores" data-id-agente="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" style="width: 100px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid #c2c5cd; text-align: center; line-height: 28px; float: left; border-right: none; cursor: pointer;">
                        <p>JOGADORES</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 30px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid #c2c5cd; text-align: center; line-height: 28px; float: left; cursor: pointer;">
                        <i id="botao_ver_opcoes" data-id-agente="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div id="opcoes-{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" style="width: 130px; margin-top: 30px; background-color: white; border: 1px solid #c2c5cd; z-index: 10; position: absolute; display: none; border-top: none;">
                        <!--<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-add-credito" id="add-credito-btn" data-id-agente="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" data-id-line="{{ $agent_tree->credit_line }}" style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">TRANSFERIR</div>-->
                        <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-info-agente" id="info-user-btn" data-id-agente="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">INFORMAÇÕES</div>
                        <!--<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-update-senha" id="change-pwd-btn" data-id-agente="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">SENHA</div>
                        <div style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">MENSAGEM</div>-->
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <!-- NOTA: O @endforeach que estava aqui não devia estar -->
            <tr id="content-{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" style="display: none;" bgcolor="#d6d6df">
                <td colspan="10" style="padding:0; margin:0; ">
                    <div class="table-responsive alt-table">
                        <table style=" margin: 10px auto; width: 50%;" class="table table-bordered">
                             <thead>
                                <tr bgcolor="#e0e0e2">
                                    <th class="table-check">
                                        ID do Jogador
                                    </th>
                                    <th>Username</th>
                                    <th>Primeiro Nome</th>
                                    <th>Sobrenome</th>
                                    <th>Balance</th>
                                    <th>Ações</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach($players as $players_dados)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="table-check">
                                            {{ $players_dados->id }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-check">
                                            {{ $players_dados->username }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-check">
                                            {{ $players_dados->f_name }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-check">
                                            {{ $players_dados->l_name }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-check">
                                            {{ number_format($players_dados->balance,2,",","") }} €
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-check">
                                            <div class="btn-group">
                                                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-add-credito-jogador" id="add-credito-btn-jogador" data-id-jogador="{{ $players_dados->id }}" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-update-senha" id="change-pwd-btn" data-id-jogador="{{ $players_dados->id }}" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach 
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!-- NOTA: Aqui termina a parte do código que
                             colaste na pergunta; continuo as tags de
                             fechamento assumindo que não há mais nada
                             de interessante além daqui -->
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <!-- NOTA: É *AQUI* que devia estar o @endforeach -->
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Quanto ao teu "JSON" (na verdade, PHP que retorna um fragmento de HTML dentro de o que suponho ser um dicionário JSON), ele *parece* correto, assumindo que o `}` que puseste na antepenúltima linha (antes do `return response()->json($return);`) é o final de um *loop* que itera sobre os utilizadores e que `$conteudo_players` é corretamente gerado para cada utilizador nesse *loop* putativo. Só não percebo por que há duas maneiras de gerar a mesma tabela, mas esse código deveria estar correto.

Comment: Nao percebi como o codigo como colocou na resposta esta igual ao meu pelo menos pelo que vejo diga-me se estou enganado

Comment: Estás enganado: Nota como, no teu código, o primeiro `@endforeach` está _imediatamente antes_ da linha `<tr id="content-{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}"...` Da mesma forma que pus no código que pus na resposta. Este é o erro: o @endforeach tem que estar imediatamente antes do `</tbody>` além do fim do código que puseste na pergunta (o teu html só vai até o fechamento da `<table>` interna que contém as informações dos jogadores).

Comment: Eu nao estou a perceber peco desculpa podes editar a resposta e por como deve ficar exactamente o meu html que pus na pergunta da maneira certa

Comment: E tambem como deve ficar o JSON se faz favor eu retorno o json por jquery atraves da funcao after()

Comment: Pus o HTML corrigido, só com alguns comentários dizendo `<!-- NOTA: etc. -->` para chamar a atenção às diferenças com o código que postaste. Vê se resta alguma dúvida, e se puderes, explica por que e como esse _markup_ que geras por AJAX substitui o que geras usando esse código HTML + preprocessador.

Comment: Corrigi da forma que puses-te mas nao resolveu depois de listar todos eu abro cada jogador o primiero por exemplo abre abaixo de todo da tabela os utilizadores que tem o icon + carrego lista os utilizadores abaixo associados a ele se abrir nesses utilizadores a listagem dos jogadores aparece no sitio certo mas o utiliuzador pai se for ver os jogadores dele mostra no fim da tabela tambem

Comment: Não sera porque eu estou a usar isto var pai = $(this).parent().parent(); e depois para listar os users qaundo carrego no + uso isto pai.after(data.conteudo); nao sera por isso

Comment: Se `this` se refere ao `<div id="show-list">` com o ícone `+` que carregas, sim, mas pode ser que o evento esteja pendurado no `<td>` que é o pai dele. Talvez seja mais seguro que uses `$(this).parent('tr')`, que buscará entre os ancestrais de `this` o mais recente que se adeque ao seletor que passas por parâmetro — neste caso concreto, a primeira _tag_ `<tr>` que ele encontrar. De todo modo, verifica pra mim quem é o `this` quando essa variável `pai` é definida.

Comment: sim o this se refere <div id="show-list"> acho eu normalmente o this e assim eu meti parent('tr') e ao clicar no mais nem lista nada

Comment: isto var pai = $(this).parent().parent(); foi feito por um amigo meu e funciona mas penso que nao e o mais correcto isso foi feito para que quando clicar no mais listar sempre os users associados a ele abaixo dele  pode ser isso que esta a dar problemas porque nao essa a forma correcta